# Non-repetitive random number in numpy

Tags: random, numpy, numbers, non-repetitive

How can I generate non-repetitive random numbers in numpy?

```
list = np.random.random_integers(20,size=(10))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "non-repetitive"?  That the sequence of random numbers never recurs?  This is not possible, since the state of the random number generator needs to fit in the finite memory of a computer.  Or do you mean that no single number occurs twice?

Comment: Non-repetitive means that you have a list with no duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps you need a random permutation? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

Answer (score 180, accepted):

[`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) offers a `replace` argument to sample without replacement:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
numbers = rng.choice(20, size=10, replace=False)
```

If you're on a pre-1.17 NumPy, without the `Generator` API, you can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) from the standard library:

```
print(random.sample(range(20), 10))
```

You can also use `numpy.random.shuffle()` and slicing, but this will be less efficient:

```
a = numpy.arange(20)
numpy.random.shuffle(a)
print a[:10]
```

There's also a `replace` argument in the legacy `numpy.random.choice` function, but this argument was implemented inefficiently and then left inefficient due to random number stream stability guarantees, so its use isn't recommended. (It basically does the shuffle-and-slice thing internally.)

**Some timings:**

```
import timeit
print("when output size/k is large, np.random.default_rng().choice() is far far quicker, even when including time taken to create np.random.default_rng()")
print(1, timeit.timeit("rng.choice(a=10**5, size=10**4, replace=False, shuffle=False)", setup="import numpy as np; rng=np.random.default_rng()", number=10**3)) #0.16003450006246567
print(2, timeit.timeit("np.random.default_rng().choice(a=10**5, size=10**4, replace=False, shuffle=False)", setup="import numpy as np", number=10**3)) #0.19915290002245456

print(3, timeit.timeit("random.sample( population=range(10**5), k=10**4)", setup="import random", number=10**3))   #5.115292700007558

print("when output size/k is very small, random.sample() is quicker")
print(4, timeit.timeit("rng.choice(a=10**5, size=10**1, replace=False, shuffle=False)", setup="import numpy as np; rng=np.random.default_rng()", number=10**3))  #0.01609779999125749
print(5, timeit.timeit("random.sample( population=range(10**5), k=10**1)", setup="import random", number=10**3))  #0.008387799956835806
```

So `numpy.random.Generator.choice` is what you usually want to go for, except for very small output size/`k`.

Comment: What if my n is not 20, but like 1000000, but I need only 10 unique numbers from it, is there more memory efficient approach?

Comment: @mrgloom In Python 3, `random.sample(range(n), 10))` will be efficient even for very large `n`, since a `range` object is just a small wrapper storing start, stop and step values, but does not create the full list of integers.  In Python 2, you can replace `range` with `xrange` to get a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 146):

I think `numpy.random.sample` doesn't work right, now. This is my way:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(range(20), 10, replace=False)
```

Comment: Instead of `range(n)` (or `arange(n)`) as the first argument of `choice`, it is equivalent to just pass `n`, e.g. `choice(20, 10, replace=False)`.

Comment: Note that `np.random.choice(a, size, replace=False)` is very slow for large `a` - on my machine, around 30 ms for a=1M.

Comment: To avoid time and memory issues for very large `n` use `numpy.random.Generator.choice` (starting with numpy v1.17)

Comment: The main disadvantage I see is np.random.choice does not have an axis parameter -> it's only for 1d arrays.

Comment: @ssp Then just get enough random numbers and reshape...

Answer (score 8):

Years later, some timeits for choosing 40000 out of 10000^2
(Numpy 1.8.1, imac 2.7 GHz):

```
import random
import numpy as np

n = 10000
k = 4
np.random.seed( 0 )

%timeit np.random.choice( n**2, k * n, replace=True )  # 536 µs ± 1.58 µs
%timeit np.random.choice( n**2, k * n, replace=False ) # 6.1 s ± 9.91 ms

# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/index.html
randomstate = np.random.default_rng( 0 )
%timeit randomstate.choice( n**2, k * n, replace=False, shuffle=False )  # 766 µs ± 2.18 µs
%timeit randomstate.choice( n**2, k * n, replace=False, shuffle=True )   # 1.05 ms ± 1.41 µs

%timeit random.sample( range( n**2 ), k * n )          # 47.3 ms ± 134 µs
```

(Why choose 40000 out of 10000^2 ?
To generate large
[scipy.sparse.random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.random.html)
matrices -- scipy 1.4.1 uses `np.random.choice( replace=False )`, slooooow.)

Tip of the hat to numpy.random people.

Comment: TL;DR: Use [`np.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) rather than `np.random.choice`, which gains a 6000x speedup in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this by sorting as well:

```
random_numbers = np.random.random([num_samples, max_int])
samples = np.argsort(random_numbers, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python set-list conversion can be used. 10 random non repetitive numbers between 0 and 20 can be obtained as:

```
import random
numbers=set()
while(len(numbers)<10):
    numbers.add(random.randint(0,20))

numbers=list(numbers)
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply generate an array that contains the required range of numbers, then shuffle them by repeatedly swapping a random one with the 0th element in the array. This produces a random sequence that doesn't contain duplicate values.

Comment: Another property of the resulting random sequence is that [it is not particularly random](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).

Comment: @SvenMarnach - For most purposes, though, it's random enough. He could use the double-random approach if he wanted it more random.

Comment: This is pointless.  The OP can use library calls to do it right.  They are easier to use, run faster and are more readable than a custom version.  I can't think of any reason why I should use a wrong algorithm here just because it is probably "random enough", when using the right algorithm has no disadvantage whatsoever.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - Fair enough. I don't know numpy, so I was just offering a potential solution.