# Why is numpy.random.choice so slow?

Tags: python, random, numpy

While writing a script I discovered the numpy.random.choice function. I implemented it because it was was much cleaner than the equivalent if statement. However, after running the script I realized it is **significantly** slower than the if statement.

The following is a MWE. The first method takes 0.0 s, while the second takes 7.2 s. If you scale up the *i* loop, you will see how fast random.choice slows down.

Can anyone comment on why random.choice is so much slower?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rand
import time as tm

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tStart = tm.time()
for i in xrange(100):
    for j in xrange(1000):
        tmp = rand.rand()
        if tmp < 0.25:
            var = 1
        elif tmp < 0.5:
            var = -1
print('Time: %.1f s' %(tm.time() - tStart))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tStart = tm.time()
for i in xrange(100):
    for j in xrange(1000):
        var = rand.choice([-1, 0, 1], p = [0.25, 0.5, 0.25])
print('Time: %.1f s' %(tm.time() - tStart))
```

Comment: That's not really a fair comparison. Each time, numpy has to take the cumulative sum of the p list, put that into a new vector, and then iterate over it. You're effectively doing preprocessing by knowing that there are only three variables, and that the sum of the first and third is .5. Beyond that, as noted below, numpy is optimized for vectorized operations, not for doing a single simple operation thousands of times.

Comment: Also, use `timeit`, not `time` on its own.

Comment: See [non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505651/non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy/8505834#8505834) for some timeits for choosing 40000 out of 10000^2
in Numpy 1.8.1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're using it wrong. Vectorize the operation, or numpy will offer no benefit:

```
var = numpy.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=1000, p=[0.25, 0.5, 0.25])
```

Timing data:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''numpy.random.choice([-1, 0, 1],
...                                      size=1000,
...                                      p=[0.25, 0.5, 0.25])''',
...               'import numpy', number=10000)
2.380380242513752

>>> timeit.timeit('''
... var = []
... for i in xrange(1000):
...     tmp = rand.rand()
...     if tmp < 0.25:
...         var.append(1)
...     elif tmp < 0.5:
...         var.append(-1)
...     else:
...         var.append(0)''',
... setup='import numpy.random as rand', number=10000)
5.673041396894519
```

Answer (score 4):

It took me a really long time to figure out that my data generator is very slow due to the random key sampling via `np.random.choice`.

In case the non-uniform distribution is **NOT** needed, then here is the workable solution I found.

Replace

```
def get_random_key(a_huge_key_list):
    return np.random.choice(a_huge_key_list)
```

with

```
def get_random_key(a_huge_key_list):
    L = len(a_huge_key_list)
    i = np.random.randint(0, L)
    return a_huge_key_list[i]
```

which gives a speedup of x60.

Comment: Hmm; interesting. Any idea why this makes such a difference to the speed? From the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0a113ed38dd538983a00c0ff5d87a56df1b93867/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1162), your expanded version doesn't look _so_ different from what NumPy is already doing.

Comment: Ah, after some testing, I suspect the main cause of the timing difference you're seeing is that you're using an actual Python `list` as input, and `np.random.choice` implicitly converts that to a NumPy array first, while your second version of `get_random_key` avoids that conversion. It's the list-to-array conversion that becomes the bottleneck for large lists. When I test the two variants on a 1d NumPy _array_ of 10**6 elements (rather than a list), the timings are much closer for me: the second version is about 50% faster.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Your comment was invaluable to me. I had a case, where np.random.choice was very slow due to repeated list -> numpy conversion. I changed my code, and now I first convert my list to np.array bofore many calls to np.random.choice, and I have saved like > 90% of execution time.

Answer (score 4):

This solution with a cumulative score is about 25x faster:

```
def choice(options,probs):
    x = np.random.rand()
    cum = 0
    for i,p in enumerate(probs):
        cum += p
        if x < cum:
            break
    return options[i]


options = ['a','b','c','d']
probs = [0.2,0.6,0.15,0.05]
runs = 100000


now = time.time()
temp = []
for i in range(runs):
    op = choice(options,probs)
    temp.append(op)
temp = Counter(temp)
for op,x in temp.items():
    print(op,x/runs)
print(time.time()-now)

print("")
now = time.time()
temp = []
for i in range(runs):
    op = np.random.choice(options,p = probs)
    temp.append(op)
temp = Counter(temp)
for op,x in temp.items():
    print(op,x/runs)
print(time.time()-now)
```

Running it I get:

```
b 0.59891
a 0.20121
c 0.15007
d 0.04981
0.16232800483703613

b 0.5996
a 0.20138
c 0.14856
d 0.05046
3.8451428413391113
```

Comment: Small refactoring:

```python

def fast_choice(options, probs):
    x = random.random()#np.random.rand()
    cum = 0
    for i, p in enumerate(probs):
        cum += p
        if x < cum:
            return options[i]
    return options[-1]

```

Comment: Your list is not a numpy array. This creates a significant overhead for numpy.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the generality of `np.random.choice` is slowing it down, more so for small samples than large ones.

A crude vectorization of the `if` version is:

```
def foo(n):
    x = np.random.rand(n)
    var = np.zeros(n)
    var[x<.25] = -1
    var[x>.75] = 1
    return var
```

Running in `ipython` I get:

```
timeit np.random.choice([-1,0,1],size=1000,p=[.25,.5,.25])
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 us per loop

timeit foo(1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.4 us per loop

timeit np.random.choice([-1,0,1],size=100000,p=[.25,.5,.25])
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop

timeit foo(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.12 ms per loop
```

So for the `1000` size, `choice` is 3-4x slower, but with larger vectors, the difference starts to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

For others who stumble upon this question and do not draw 1,000 samples 10,000 times but 1 sample 10,000 times, there exists a faster alternative since Python 3.6. The function random.choices is ~20 times faster compared to numpy.random.choice.

```
timeit("random.choices([-1, 0, 1], k=1, weights=[.25, .5, .25])", 
setup="import random", number=10000)
# >>> 0.018841781999981322
```

vs

```
timeit("numpy.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=1, p=[.25, .5, .25])", 
setup="import numpy", number=10000)
# >>> 0.40612822200000664
```

Comment: Wow that's a pretty insane difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers involve at least one of the following:

1- Using python list as an input for numpy.random.choice and creating overhead.

2- Using prior knowledge that the len(array) will be 3.

3- The distribution is uniform.

For arbitrary length lists, one of the fastest algorithms would divide the list into 2 at each step. For example the following code would work in generic cases.

```
def my_random_function(collection, p):
    miles = []
    current = 0
    for prob in p:
        miles.append(current)
        current += prob
    if not math.isclose(current,1):
        raise ValueError()
    x = random.random()
    _all = list(zip(collection,miles))
    while(len(_all)!= 1):
        if _all[len(_all)//2][1] < x:
            _all = _all[len(_all)//2:]
        else:
            _all = _all[0: len(_all)//2]
    return _all[0][0]
```

To compare the differences I prepared two cases:

```
small_list = list(range(3))
small_array = np.arange(3)
#create a random probability list
small_p = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
small_p = [prob/sum(small_p) for prob in small_p]
small_p_np = np.array(small_p)

large_list = list(range(10000))
large_array = np.arange(10000)
#create a random probability list
large_p = [random.random() for i in range(10000)]
large_p = [prob/sum(large_p) for prob in large_p]
large_p_np = np.array(large_p)
```

The results are as follows:

```
%timeit np.random.choice(small_array, p= small_p_np)

68.1 µs ± 196 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit my_random_function(small_list, small_p)

5.13 µs ± 26.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.random.choice(large_array, p= large_p_np)

279 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit my_random_function(large_list, large_p)

3.26 ms ± 5.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As the results show numpy.random.choice takes more than x10 time for small collections, but quickly becomes the better choice when there are more elements. It seems that this function has a big overhead, and better be avoided for small lists in performance critical parts of the code.