# How to change a certain count of numpy matrix elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a square numpy 2D matrix.

```
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
```

And I need to set a certain count of random matrix values to 0. Let's say it is 5 elements. That means any 5 from 16 matrix values must be set to 0. For example new matrix could be

```
2 2 0 0
0 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
0 2 0 2
```

or

```
2 0 2 2
2 2 0 2
2 2 0 2
0 2 2 0
```

or some else.

How could I do this efficient way?

Comment: Do you want a randomized way of setting `x` zeros in the array or always setting first `x` values to 0 would suffice?

Comment: @Raj, I want to set to zero elements with random position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import random
arr1d = arr.ravel()
randidx = random.sample(range(len(arr1d)), 5)
arr1d[randidx] = 0
```

This modifies `arr` because `ravel()` returns a view, not a copy.

For more on how the random numbers can be generated, see: [Non-repetitive random number in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505651/non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy)

Answer (score -1):

lets say your matrix is "matrix"

```
import random
for i in range(5):
    random1=random.randint(0,size_x_ofmatrix)
    random2=random.randint(0,size_y_ofmatrix)
    matrix[random1,random2]=0
```

Comment: This does not check for repetition, so it may set less than five elements to zero. (It also has a typo or three, but that's less of a problem.)

Comment: Indeed :( btw, what do you mean by typo of three?

Comment: "or", not "of": `randin`, `random` and `random` instead of `randint`, `random1` and `random2`.

Comment: Thx. I was a little speedy!