# How to insert a value in 2D random lists?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a minesweeper with python. Now I'm trying to insert 10 mines into the lists randomly. Please help me to figure it out!

```
import random
import numpy as np
from random import randint

#assign a value of mines and create 8 x 8 empty array.
mines = 1000
arr1 = np.empty((8,8))

#insert 10 mines into random lists.
z = 1

if z < 11 :
    np.append(arr1, np.array(random.randint[mines]))
    z = z + 1
```

Comment: `np.random.choice(8 * 8, 10, replace=False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-repetitive random number in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505651/non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

since you have a total of 64 places

get a random int in 0,63(total 64)

and figure out the x and y

```
import random
import numpy as np
from random import randint

#assign a value of mines and create 8 x 8 empty array.
mines = 1000
arr1 = np.empty((8,8))
print(arr1)

minesRemaining = 10
while minesRemaining > 0:
    r = randint (0,63)
    i = r//8
    j = r%8
    if arr1[i][j]!=1000:
        arr1[i][j]=1000
        minesRemaining-=1
print(arr1)
```

```
[[2.2588207e-316 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
 [0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000
  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]]
[[1000.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0. 1000.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [1000. 1000.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0. 1000.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 1000.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0. 1000.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0. 1000.    0.    0.    0.]
 [1000.    0.    0.    0. 1000.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a minefield:

```
grid = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=np.bool)
mask = np.random.choice(grid.size, 10, replace=False)
grid.reshape(-1)[mask] = True
```

One example output:

```
>>> grid
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = np.array(list(range(64))
bar = numpy.random.choice(foo, 10)
baz = np.zeros(64)
baz[bar] = 1000
baaz = reshape((8, 8))
```