# Randomized strings without term repetition?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to randomized some words in Python, but I get lines with repeated terms. How can I avoid it?

My code:

---

```
words = ['blue,', 'orange,', 'yellow,', 'white,','pink,']

list=[]
for i in range(90):
    r = ''.join(random.choices(words, k=random.randint(1, 5)))
    if r not in list: list.append(r)
```

What I get:

---

```
orange,white,orange,white,blue,  <-- Here Orange & white are twice
```

Thanks!

Comment: `random.randint()` samples without replacement. Here's an example of how to get random numbers without replacement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505651/non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy

Comment: Thanks @AriAnisfeld